# Angular 2 how does auxiliary routes work in 2.1.0?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have this route:

```
{
   path: 'dashboard',
   loadChildren: '../pages/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
}
```

With the `dashboard`'s router looking like this:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ComponentsModule,
    SharedModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        component: DashboardComponent
      }
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [
    DashboardComponent
  ]
})
export class DashboardRouterModule {}
```

And in my parent view (which is `/admin`, dashboard route is `/admin/dashboard`), I have a `<router-outlet name="admin"></router-outlet>`, but I can't seem to figure out the syntax for this because I just get a bunch of errors whenever I try.

Here's what I tried:

```
{
   path: 'dashboard(admin: '')',
   loadChildren: '../pages/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
}

{
   path: 'dashboard(admin: dashboard)',
   loadChildren: '../pages/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
}
```

(router):

```
 {
   path: '(dashboard: '')',
   component: DashboardComponent
 }

 {
   path: '',
   component: DashboardComponent,
   outlet: 'admin'
 }
```

What is the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the parent router:

```
{
   path: 'dashboard',
   loadChildren: '../pages/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule',
   outlet: 'admin'
}
```

and go with `/(admin:dashboard)`

Comment: Seems to work, can the url be prettified in some way so that it doesn't actually say `localhost:4200/admin/(admin: dashboard)`? I want the url to be `localhost:4200/admin/dashboard`.

Comment: And how do you write child routes of dashboard into the same `router-outlet`? Like `http://localhost:4200/admin/(admin:dashboard/brands)`

Comment: I think you can't prettify the url, that's the correct syntax for auxiliary route.
An idea could be to have a `admin/dashboard` and use the ngOnInit method in DashboardComponent to open an internal named outlet

Comment: About child routes of dashboard... `/(admin:dashboard/brands)` seems to be correct

Comment: That doesn't work unfortunately, `http://localhost:4200/admin/(admin:dashboard/brands)` and `http://localhost:4200/(admin:dashboard/brands)` both fail..

Comment: Nevermind, turns out you can't have the `outlet` set on the deep children, only the parent is enough.

Comment: Do you have a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in your DashboardComponent template?

Comment: No, the child views should use the same outlet as the dashboard. But it's working now.

Comment: Turns out it wasn't working, I just got fooled by my layout. How can I make the brands view load into the same `router-outlet` as the dashboard?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40131110/how-to-render-a-grandchild-view-into-the-same-router-outlet-as-the-first-child